# Azure Batch pool create error, saying that the format of the request body is invalid for custom image

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-batch, azure-vm

I am using the following command to create an azure batch pool. Please note I am using a custom image. Also please note that I have authenticated batch with Active Directory:

```
az batch pool create --json-file pool.json
```

The pool.json file looks like the following

```
{
"id": "WEPool004",
"vmSize": "Standard_NC6",
"virtualMachineConfiguration": {
    "imageReference": {
        "virtual_machine_image_id": "/subscriptions/{sub id}/resourceGroups/{resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{image definition name}",
        "publisher": null,
        "offer": null,
        "sku": null
    },
    "nodeAgentSKUId": "batch.node.ubuntu 18.04"
},
"targetDedicatedNodes": 1
```

}

Azure CLI complains with the error:

```
Reason: The specified resource id must be of the format /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/{galleryName}/images/{galleryImageName}/versions/{galleryImageVersionName} or /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/{galleryName}/images/{galleryImageName}
```

Now this means that [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images) page is outdated, since I have followed their format.
If I follow the format specified in the error, I need to make an image gallery and subsequently an image definition. If I do make those two and then replace the `virtual_machine_image_id`, it complains NOT on the azure CLI, but on the pools page of the azure portal, it displays the following error message:

```
Message:
Desired number of dedicated nodes could not be allocated

Values:
Reason - The specified image is not found
```

So either I encounter the error that virtual_machine_image_id is of invalid format, or it is simply not found. Hence, I can hypothesize that I am making an error while I make the image definition and image gallery. Please can anyone point to me to the correct direction.
Please note that I followed [this](https://github.com/azurebigcompute/recipes/blob/master/Azure%20Batch/CustomImages/CustomImagePython.md) tutorial for Azure CLI for batch.

Answer (score 0):

The error I made was that I did not create a snapshot. I used the URL from the image definition created using that snapshot as specified in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/image-version-snapshot-cli). Now its working.